# Razor view with 2 separate forms when the second form relies on input values that the user selects in the parent form

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

On my parent view I have a primary form that the user will be filling out which will be using the EventWizardViewModel (shown below). However, midway through the form the user will need to use a tool to generate a list of ExpirationDates.. this tool is a form of its own, but when posting it to the server it relies on the StartDate and EndDate that the user selected when filling out the primary form.

My plan for this tool is to open its form in a dialog window and set all of the asp-for tags to be like: ExpirationDatesFormViewModel.ProductType, ExpirationDatesFormViewModel.CountFilter, and so on... However I am not really sure how and where I can set the StartDate and EndDate of the ExpirationDatesFormViewModel..

Ultimately the user will click a Generate Expiration Dates button at the bottom of the dialog window, which will do an AJAX post sending the ExpirationDatesFormViewModel to the Controller Action Method which in turn returns a list of Expiration dates to the parent page.

Any advice/help on having a single razor view with 2 forms on it when the second form relies on values of the inputs on the primary form before the primary form is ever submitted would be great. The primary form doesn't get submitted until long after the tool has been used.

---

**UPDATE:** showing the Razor code so you guys have a better understanding of what the HTML looks like. You will see that there is a primary form which the user starts filling out and then midway through the process they are able to use a tool that opens up in a dialog window and generates some helpful information for them. I guess my confusion is whether I have my ViewModels setup correctly for this to work where I can use the built in ASP.NET model binding functionality with both forms and a single view model for the page. The trick here is that the secondary form relies on StartDate and EndDate values that the user filled out on the primary form.

```
<div id="window_GetExpirationDatesTool">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form asp-action="GetExpirationDates" id="expirationDatesToolForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ExpirationDates.ProductCategory" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ExpirationDates.ProductCategory" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductCategories" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ExpirationDates.ProductType" class="control-label"></label>
                    <select asp-for="ExpirationDates.ProductType" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductTypes" class="form-control"></select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ExpirationDates.CountFilter" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ExpirationDates.CountFilter" type="number" value="0" min="-100" max="100" step="1" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Generate Expiration Dates" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form asp-action="Create" id="primaryForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="StartDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="StartDate" />
            <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="text-danger" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EndDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EndDate" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="text-danger" />
        </div>

        @* MANY MORE PRIMARY FORM FIELDS HERE *@

        @* THIS BUTTON OPENS THE DIALOG WITH THE SECOND FORM *@
        <button id="btnOpenGenerateExpirationDatesDialog" class="btn btn-primary">Click to Auto-Generate Expiration Dates</button>
        <div>Autogenerated expiration dates get placed here on ajax-success</div>

        @* MANY MORE PRIMARY FORM FIELDS HERE *@

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
</form>
```

The controller action methods (notice on of them accepts the primary page vm and the other accepts only the expirationdates vm:

```
// POST: Products/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(EventWizardViewModel vm)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TODO: Save everything
    }

    return View();
}

// POST: Products/GetResetDates
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult GetExpirationDates(ExpirationDatesFormViewModel vm)
{
    //TODO: Get expiration dates

    return Json(expirationDates);
}
```

**My view models:**
EventWizardViewModel.cs (page view model and primary form view model)

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}
// Many more properties directly related to the Parent form here
public ExpirationDatesFormViewModel ExpirationDates {get; set;}
```

ExpirationDatesFormViewModel.cs (sub view model which is a property of the main page view model and contains fields used for expiration dates form)

```
// Note that these 2 properties are the same ones from the Parent form's view model
public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
public DateTime EndDate {get; set;}

public string ProductCategory {get; set;}
public string ProductType {get; set;}
public int CountFilter {get; set;}
```

I just feel like something is off with what I am doing, whether it is the way my ViewModels are setup or the way my forms in the razor are setup, maybe the tool shouldn't even be a form trying to use the asp.net features and simply just use pure js/jquery to to an AJAX post.

Comment: You will need javascript/jquery to get the values from the main form and update the values in the dialog (and note that your forms cannot be nested)

Comment: How are you posting the second form?

Comment: @tede24 I am posting the second form when the user clicks a button in the dialog window, it does an AJAX post which returns a list of dates and displays them on the page next to the main form and then the dialog closes..

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yeah my forms are not nested, one of them is in a div that is opened in a dialog window. So what you are saying is don't worry about doing it through model binding? I kind of wanted to be able to post the entire form using ASP.NET model binding. I currently am doing a completely custom AJAX post by getting the 2 values that I need from the parent form using JavaScript and all of the values from the dialog form using JavaScript and just posting it.

Comment: You can still use model binding. If the `name` of the controls in the dialog match a model you posting back to, then you will get model binding, and ditto for your main form.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you look at the update I made to my post on this and let me know if I am on the right track to be able to do model binding with both forms, 2 separate posts to 2 separate action methods but sharing fields.

Comment: @tede24 can you take another look and see the UPDATE part at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add StartDate and EndDate as hidden fields in the second form and fill them on submit event from input values in main form. That way you will get ViewModel fields bound as you want:

View:

```
<div id="window_GetExpirationDatesTool">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form asp-action="GetExpirationDates" id="expirationDatesToolForm">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ExpirationDates.StartDate">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ExpirationDates.EndDate">
                ...
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //on document ready
    $(function(){
        //bind form submit event
        $('#expirationDatesToolForm').submit(function(e){
            //set the input values (check field names please)
            $('#ExpirationDates_StartDate').val($('#StartDate').val());
            $('#ExpirationDates_EndDate').val($('#EndDate').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also there is a mistake on the Action method, as you are declaring the viewmodel as ExpirationDatesFormViewModel, but your second form's input names will have ExpirationDates_ prefix (because you are doing asp-for="ExpirationDates.xx"). 
Here are some possible solutions for this:

1. Change action method parameter's type to EventWizardViewMode so it has ExpirationDates property to match the prefix (I don't like this but it works)
2. Move your 2nd form to a Partial and pass it Model.ExpirationDates as model, so in that partial model is declared as `@model ExpirationDatesFormViewModel` avoiding input names prefixes

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I want. I am going to try and implement it. Do the action method params in my controller seem correct or should they both be accepting EventWizardViewModel?

Comment: So I was able to get it working by changing the parameter for GetExpirationDates to be GetExpirationDates(EventWizardViewModel  vm).. I think my main issue as you noted was this parameter. Now I I can simply do vm.ExpirationDates to access the values that I need within the function. I will look into moving the second form into a partial later on, hoping I will still be able to set values on the parent after the 2nd form is submitted though.